# Send multiple requests API with tabulator evenment rowClick

Tags: javascript, rest, request, tabulator

I use a tabulator to display data, when I select one or more rows I run a fetch request with an `cellValue.id` as a parameter in my request, I want to send multiple requests to as selected id's, how can i do that:

```
rowDblClick: function (e,row) {
            var selectedData = $("#scenario-table").tabulator("getSelectedData"); //get array of currently selected data.


            var flowRequest = ApiBaseUrl + '/api/indic/v1/fpl_flows/segment/' + cellValue.id ;

           fetch(flowRequest, {
               credentials: "include" /*, signal: abortCtrl.signal*/
             })
             .then(function(resp) {
               return resp.json();
             })
             .then(function(json) {
               data_flow.push(json.data);
             })
```

Thank's for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can call the fetch function multiple times inside the click handling callback if needed:

```js
rowDblClick: function (e,row) {

   //first request
   fetch("http://url1.com", {
       credentials: "include" /*, signal: abortCtrl.signal*/
   })
   .then(() => {})
   .catch(() => {})

   //second request
   fetch("http://urle.com", {
       credentials: "include" /*, signal: abortCtrl.signal*/
   })
   .then(() => {})
   .catch(() => {})
}
```

in the example above both requests would run simultaneously, if the second request depends on the response of the first you could either chain the promises or make the second request inside the `then1 of the first.

Comment: Thank you @Oli Flokerd for your help

Comment: No problem, if you found this helpful, would you mind marking it as the answer so that others can find the same help more easily?